# List non-posts pages in relevant category pages

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll blog up and running, but I'd like to do something that seems a bit unorthodox. 
Essentially, I've got blog posts in `/_posts`, and a set of static pages in another folder at `/projects`.

The top of these projects page looks like this:

```
---
layout: project
title: My cool project
categories:
- Data Journalism
status: active
---
```

Now, the biggie: Each category (such as *Data Journalism* in the example above) has a page with a unique URL, where posts belonging to this category are aggregated.

**I would like projects belonging to these categories to be aggregated on these same pages,** eg the *Data Journalism* category page would have a list of projects and a list of posts, all of which are part of this category.

I managed to list all the projects on each category page with

```
<ul class="posts">
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.layout == 'project' %}
      {% if page.status == 'active' %}
        <h2><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h2>
        <div> {{ page.description }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

added in `_layouts/category_index.html`. But it shows *all* projects, not only the one belonging to the page category. In the example, `My cool project` should only be listed in the `Data Journalism` category page.

Can you help? I'd be most grateful!

**EDIT:** Thanks to Davic Jacquel for the solution. His answer's below, marked as solved, and here is the tweak I had to make:

```
<ul class="posts">
  {% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.layout == 'project' and p.status == 'active' %}
    {% assign cat = p.categories | downcase %}
      {% if cat contains page.category %}
        <h2><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></h2>
        <div> {{ p.description }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** : reading your plugin code makes me realize that you have a `page.category` variable in all your categories pages.

**Note** : current page's data are stored in the `page` variable. So, when you loop, try not use `page` as a storage variable to avoid collision.

In *_layouts/category_index.html* :

```
---
layout: default
---
<ul class="posts">
  {% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.layout == 'project' and p.status == 'active' %}
      {% if p.categories contains page.category %}
        <h2><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></h2>
        <div> {{ p.description }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice about avoiding collision!

Unfortunately, the category pages don't have a `cat` property in the header. Any idea how I could set it? The `_layouts/category_index.html` seems to generate these pages automatically.

Comment: Did you have an example of page that use this template ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it's all local now. 

These pages will sit at something like `{{ site.url }}/categories/data-journalism`, to keep the name of the example.

Comment: @david-jacquet: I'm using this ruby file to generate the categories, by the way: https://github.com/recurser/jekyll-plugins

Comment: Edited my answer. Maybe it's more understandable.

Comment: You're a star, thank you so much! I had to `downcase` `p.categories` so there would be a match. See my edited question